# How to covert lists of dict time series data to pandas series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Suppose I have 1000 items time-series dictionary data saved in the python list and some nontime-series keys. 
The problems are that there are some different time-series keys each list.
Here are two examples of data items in the list.

```
[{'00:00:00': 1430801.0,
 '00:05:00': 1430806.0,
 '00:10:00': 1430811.0,
 '00:15:00': 1430815.0,
 '00:20:00': 1430821.0,
 'dt': '2016-07-18',
 'a': 'Jack'
 'b': 'Tony'},
 {'00:10:00': 1430201.0,
 '00:25:00': 1430106.0,
 '00:40:00': 1430311.0,
 '00:55:00': 1430415.0,
 '01:10:00': 1430521.0,
 'dt': '2016-07-19',
 'a': 'Jack'
 'b': 'Tony'}]
```

I want to covert this list to pandas Series like following:
Se[Jack_Tony]：

```
2016-07-18 00:00:00: 1430801.0
2016-07-18 00:05:00: 1430806.0
2016-07-18 00:10:00: 1430811.0
2016-07-18 00:15:00: 1430815.0
2016-07-18 00:20:00: 1430821.0
2016-07-19 00:10:00: 1430201.0
2016-07-19 00:25:00: 1430106.0
2016-07-19 00:40:00: 1430311.0
2016-07-19 00:55:00: 1430415.0
2016-07-19 01:10:00: 1430521.0
```

Comment: I'm confused as to where `Jack` and `Tony` go in the dataframe

Comment: No, Jack and Tony are useless. But they are in the original list.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the list of dicts, only keeping the stuff that looks like a timestamp, make it a dataframe, and turn it into a series with time as the index.

```
data = [{'00:00:00': 1430801.0,
 '00:05:00': 1430806.0,
 '00:10:00': 1430811.0,
 '00:15:00': 1430815.0,
 '00:20:00': 1430821.0,
 'dt': '2016-07-18',
 'a': 'Jack',
 'b': 'Tony'},
 {'00:10:00': 1430201.0,
 '00:25:00': 1430106.0,
 '00:40:00': 1430311.0,
 '00:55:00': 1430415.0,
 '01:10:00': 1430521.0,
 'dt': '2016-07-19',
 'a': 'Jack',
 'b': 'Tony'}]

import re
pat = re.compile(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')

pd.DataFrame([[r['dt']+' '+k, v] for r in data for k, v in r.items() if pat.match(k)], columns=['tm', 'v']).set_index('tm')['v']
```

Comment: Thank you, this method is feasible. But is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: You are welcome. If you find that it answers your original question, please kindly accept the answer. What do you mean by optimize it?

Comment: Hi Leo, I mean if the number of items in the list is quite large. Is there any way to optimize the speed?

Comment: I am not sure you can get it much faster than this since you do have to check every key value for whether or not it is a in a specific format. This logic only 'touches' each key value once.

Comment: @Leo, shouldn't the solution also concatenate `r['dt']` and `k` to get the timestamp including date

Comment: @HaleemurAli Thanks, and good catch! I updated the answer to include this :)